# Don't have the Kindle treat Company, Inc. as first/last name

Tags: kindle

I'm working on a Kindle eBook for a company. They want the author field to display as "Company, Inc." This works fine in Mobipocket, but when I open the file in Kindle for PC, it diplays as "Inc. Company". It appears that Kindle interprets the comma as a separator between last and first name.

If I remove the comma, it displays (more) correctly as "Company Inc.", but I would prefer to keep the comma if possible. Anyone have advice on how to make that happen?

Comment: Does however your building/compiling the azw/mobi give you access to the .opf meta-data file? If so, what's its <dc:creator>

Comment: I have full access to modify the .opf file. Currently, that field is:       <dc:creator opf:role="aut">Company, Inc.</dc:creator>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no way to solve this in Kindle. For this case, the client agreed to simply remove the comma (e.g., Company Inc.).

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a `file-as` in the hope that that will be used as the machine sort value, leaving the actual display content untouched.

```
<dc:creator opf:file-as="Company, Inc" opf:role="aut">
Company, Inc
</dc:creator>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but unfortunately it didn't work. Still showing up as "Inc. Company".